Unable to get the correct access token from Google Single Sign On, but can get correct id token when using supabase to authenticate
Currently I am unable to get the correct access token from Google Single Sign On, which the payload is some random character, but I can get correct id token from Google Single Sign on where the data shows proper json data when using supabase to authenticate.
I have verified in my google credentials

SHA1 and correct bundle ID is accurately updated on my Android Oauth2 clientID
iOS Client ID has the correct bundle id which is reflected on my Flutter App
Web Client ID was being sent to Supabase for authentication purposes
The iOS and Web Client ID has being recorded in the app_config file of my flutter.

What are the other possible reasons for this issue?
